# Send login details to Identity server via Angular 12

Tags: identityserver4

I want to pass my username and password to IdentityServer using Angular 12. I tried but cannot send it because I cannot identify the endpoint. Instead of the Angular login page, I send details via the .cshtml page. Please someone who could help me will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to send user username/password to IdentityServer from your angular application, instead you should redirect the user to IdentityServer and let the user authenticate there and then redirect back to your Angular application. That is how OpenID-Connect/IdentityServer is supposed to work.

Comment: Exactly, the most important reason for using IDP like #idenityserver is "authorization delegation", so you should not pass username/password directly to #identityserver. the Password Owner Credential is deprecated and in #oauth 2.1 is removed.